# Using a builtin GUI in openSUSE

Tags: x11, xorg, opensuse, firefox, display-manager

I want to browse the internet with firefox and found that there was no DISPLAY environment variable and I also had the following message :
You did not install any X-Server (e.g. Xorg)!
Please install at least one server to start X.
I'm aborting now.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Install gnome or kde or a multitude of other gui's.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is decide on what Desktop Environment you would like to use and install it using zypper.

[HERE](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Convert_server_to_desktop) is the official documentation on this.

Comment: Then I had the following message failed to connect to bus : no such file or directory. Failed to talk to init daemon. Can you help anymore. Thanks a lot.